# is it normal that the AclEntry.add () method does not change a permanent access permission?

Tags: java, windows, permissions, acl, java-11

I tried to add a read permission for a given file to a user on windows 10 using the AclEntry.add () method in java, the process runs normally. However, this change does not occur in windows.
I want to know if this method should assign permission permanently or only during the execution of the program.

NOTE: I am using the AclFileAttributeView interface of the Nio.File package.
In addition I packaged this jar using Launch4j to be able to run it as an administrator.

below the code I'm using.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Inicial {
   public Inicial() throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\journal");
    UserPrincipal usercop = 
    FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService().lookupPrincipalByName("Gilderlei");

    AclFileAttributeView aclFileAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, 
    AclFileAttributeView.class);
    List<AclEntry> aclEntries = aclFileAttributeView.getAcl();

    AclEntry.Builder aclEntry = AclEntry.newBuilder()
            .setType(AclEntryType.ALLOW)
            .setPrincipal(usercop)
            .setPermissions(AclEntryPermission.READ_DATA);

    AclEntry entry = aclEntry.build();
    aclEntries.clear();
    aclEntries.add(entry);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Inicial();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add the created permission to the `aclEntries` list. Java is not an ORM mapped system that automatically writes back any data changes.

Therefore you have to call at least [setAcl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html#setAcl-java.util.List-)

```
aclFileAttributeView.setAcl(aclEntries);
```

at the end of your code.